# Excel VBA loop for adding worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently trying to figure out how to create a loop which is based on the number of rows within the active sheet.
I am creating a data converter, and the data I am converting to can only be a maximum of 4000 rows. My source data can vary in size so I need to be able to count the number of rows on the active sheet and if there are more than 4000, create a new worksheet (with a number incremented name e.g Output1, Output2 etc.), go back to the sheet I was counting on, cut rows 4001 to end and paste this onto the new sheet. The loop should repeat until the count is less than 4001 and come to an end.

I have already written the part which creates the output as it should look, I solely need to be able to split the output over 'x' amount of sheets which are no greater than 4000 rows.

Below is how far I have gotten, I just can't crack the loop element! Thank you for your time.

```
    LastRow2 = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
    If LastRow2 > 4000 Then
    Name = Right(ws.Name, 1)
    Sheets.Add.Name = "Output1" & Name
    ActiveSheet.Previous.Select
    Range("A4001").End(xlDown).Select
    Selection.Cut
    ActiveSheet.Next.Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
         :=False, Transpose:=False
    Else: GoTo
```

Comment: `For i = 4001 to lr Step 4000`?

Comment: Do you want to copy headers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a loop that copies rows in increments of 4,000 to a new sheet and delete the remaining rows from your starting sheet once loop ends.

---

```
Sub shelter_in_place()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim ns As Worksheet

Dim lr As Long, i As Long, c As Long
lr = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
c = 1


If lr > 4000 Then
    For i = 4001 To lr Step 4000
        Set ns = Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
            ns.Name = "Output " & c
            ws.Range("A" & i).Resize(4000).EntireRow.Copy
            ns.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            c = c + 1
        Set ns = Nothing
    Next i
  ws.Range("A4001:A" & lr).EntireRow.Delete
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Appreciate it.